# Merge multiple categorial columns into a single one in SAS

Tags: sas

I have the following SAS table:

```
City  grade1  grade2  grade3
NY      A.      A.      A
CA.     B.      A.      C
```

I would like to merge the three last variables into a single one; this is the expect output:

```
City  grade  
NY      A.   
NY.     A.
NY.     A.
CA.     B.  
CA.     A. 
CA.     C.
```

I tried with Proc transpose but it seems not the right way. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Can you show what you tried?  Proc transpose can do this easily.

Comment: Why do you appear to have random periods after some of the grades and city names?

Comment: Proc transpose is the correct option. In future posts please make sure to include whatever you've attempted, even if its wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the data by the City variable so you can use it as a BY and then use PROC TRANSPOSE.

```
data have;
input City $  grade1 $ grade2 $ grade3 $;
cards;
NY      A.      A.      A
CA.     B.      A.      C
;;;;


proc sort data=have; by City;run;

proc transpose data=have out=want prefix=Grade;
by City;
var grade1-grade3;
run;

proc print data=want;run;
```

Results:

```
Obs City    _NAME_  GRADE1
1   CA. grade1  B.
2   CA. grade2  A.
3   CA. grade3  C
4   NY  grade1  A.
5   NY  grade2  A.
6   NY  grade3  A
```